# Property 'text' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Im using providers with Angular and i have 2 files

user-service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
...
sendTo(address:string, info:string, save:number) {
    interface UserResponse {
      success: string;
      error: string;
      text: string;
      id: string;
    }

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get<UserResponse>('http://website.com/api/?action=send&key=' + this.apiKey + '&to=' + address + '&save=' + (save == 1 ? 1:0) + '&info=' + encodeURI(info))
      .subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }
```

And my home.ts

```
import { UserServiceProvider } from '../../providers/user-service/user-service';
...
this.userService.sendTo(this.formGroup.get("myAddress").value, this.formGroup.get("myInfo").value, this.formGroup.get("mySave").value).then(data => {

     this.userService.getAlert(data.text, (data.id ? "ID: " + data.id:""));
     if(data.success) this.formGroup.reset();
});
```

The problem is from home.ts.

data.text give me an error: `Property 'text' does not exist on type '{}'`

Same problem happen with data.success and data.id

[image]

Comment: Try with: `return new Promise<UserResponse>`

Comment: ...also precise return type of this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't specify the return type of `sendTo`. Since it returns a Promise, TypeScript will infer the return type as `Promise<{}>`. This means the argument passed to `.then` will be of type `{}`.

You can do `return new Promise<UserResponse>` instead. However, you don't even need to use the Promise constructor since Observables have a `.toPromise` method:

```
return this.http.get<UserResponse>(...).toPromise().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

You can also update the `sendTo` definition:

```
sendTo(address:string, info:string, save:number): Promise<UserResponse> {
```

Finally, rather than using a Promise at all, you can use `.subscribe` in `home.ts`.